# How to send and email without internet connection,only local host?

Tags: c#, email, networking

I have a pc without internet connection,but its on the local host network.
I want to send an email from that pc to "PC2" and it has internet connection..

How could i do that?
I have this code so far

```
        public void SendEmailsUsingPickupDirectory()
        {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        mail.From = new MailAddress("from@mycompany.hu");
        mail.To.Add("topc2@gmail.com");

        mail.Subject = "12";
        mail.Body = "12";

        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\TestEmails");
        if (!dirInfo.Exists)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\TestEmails");
        }

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
        smtp.PickupDirectoryLocation = "C:\\TestEmails";
        smtp.Send(mail);
        }
```

But it sends nothing only creates a file in that folder,but i read on the internet that a code like that could send email without internet connectivity.
Also sorry if my english is bad.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to have SMTP server setup on PC2 (PC with internet connection). PC1 would need to have access to the pickup directory on PC2 over the network via a share. Your current code looks to be creating a folder on PC1 when it should be dropping the file in an already created folder utilized by the SMTP Server on PC2.

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
smtp.PickupDirectoryLocation = @"\\PC2\Pickup";
smtp.Send(mail);
```

Comment: This makes a .EML file in that location,but no more.
Can i do something with them?

Comment: That is correct. Please note that you are using an SMTP Client. You have to have an SMTP Server monitoring the folders. You will want to look into how to set up an SMTP Server with IIS or another product.